# Are [chicken] and [chicken-scheme] tags synonyms or candidates for a merge?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Are the [chicken](/questions/tagged/chicken) (9 questions) and [chicken-scheme](/questions/tagged/chicken-scheme) (5 questions) tags synonyms, good candidates for a merge, or separate subjects? Based on the wiki descriptions, I think they're the same. I can retag the questions since they are not that many, but any preferences as to which tag should be kept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On [their web site](http://www.call-cc.org/), the compiler is called CHICKEN, although the page is titled "CHICKEN Scheme." I think that [chicken](/questions/tagged/chicken) should not cause any misunderstanding, considering that the tag is used on Stack Overflow.

Considering there are [5 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chicken-scheme+scheme) tagged [chicken-scheme](/questions/tagged/chicken-scheme) [scheme](/questions/tagged/scheme), and [6 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chicken+scheme) tagged [chicken](/questions/tagged/chicken) [scheme](/questions/tagged/scheme), I would think [chicken](/questions/tagged/chicken) is preferable.

Comment: Too late.  I already merged [tag:chicken] --> [tag:chicken-scheme], since it was... erm, more specific.